# Jquery Logic - Can't efficiently achieve flag check

Tags: javascript, jquery, performance, function, google-maps

I am new to javascript but I am having a hard time creating code which can achieve this logic:

I am trying to achieve the following logic:

> 1. If a user enters text in location box and DOES click autosuggestion   Then geocode and set coded flag to "True"
> 2. If a user enters text in location DOES NOT click autosuggestion   Keep coded flag to "False"
> 3. If a user changes the text in location box    Make sure "coded" flag is set to "false" - Since the text doesnt match the coordinates we
>      fetched for it now
> 4. If a user clicks search button    Check "coded" flag  If true, submit form    If false, process geocode, and if successful, submit form

This is how far I got before I got stuck: [LINK](http://jsfiddle.net/crFYE/10/)

Even when I click on an autosuggested link, which initiates a geocode, and then do not change the content in the input box, when I hit search it says "Location not geocoded - Process location first". I feel like my logic in the programming is wrong but I am not sure how to fix it without lots of ugly repetitive code.

**FULL CODE**

```
geocode();

// SET COOKIE FOR TESTING PURPOSES   
    $.cookie("country", "uk");

    // GEOCODE FUNCTION
    function geocode() {

        var coded = false;
        console.log(coded);
        var input = document.getElementById('loc');
        var options = {
            types: ['geocode']
        };
        var country_code = $.cookie('country');
        console.log(country_code);
        if (country_code) {
            options.componentRestrictions = {
                'country': country_code
            };
        }
        var autocomplete = new google.maps.places.Autocomplete(input, options);
        google.maps.event.addListener(autocomplete, 'place_changed', function() {
        processLocation();
        });

// ON SUBMIT - WORK OUT IF WE ALREADY HAVE THE RESULTS FROM AUTOCOMPLETE FUNCTION
        $('#searchform').on('submit', function(e) {
             console.log(coded);
             e.preventDefault();
             if(coded == true) {
                console.log("Location already geocoded - Submitting form");
                $('#searchform').submit();
             }
            else {
                console.log("Location not geocoded - Process location first");
                processLocation();   
            }
        });

// CHECK TO SEE IF INPUT HAS CHANGED SINCE BEING GEOCODED
// IF "CODED" VAR IS FALSE THEN WE WILL GEOCODE WHEN SEARCH BUTTON HIT         
        $("#loc").bind("change paste keyup", function() {
             var coded = false;
             console.log("Content changed - Coordinates no longer valid");
        });

    };  

// GEOCODE THE LOCATION
    function processLocation(){

            var geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();
            var address = document.getElementById('loc').value;
            geocoder.geocode({
                'address': address
            },

// RESULTS - STORE COORDINATES IN FIELDS OR ERROR IF NOT SUCCESSFUL
            function(results, status) {
                if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
                    var coded = true;
                    console.log("Geocode Successful");
                    $('#lat').val(results[0].geometry.location.lat());
                    $('#lng').val(results[0].geometry.location.lng());
                } else {
                    var coded = false;
                    console.log("Geocode unsuccessful");
                    alert("Sorry - We couldn't find this location. Please try an alternative")
                }

            });
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using too many local variables `coded`. YOu should define one global flag and then can use set it.

When you so

```
function geocode() {
    ....
    var coded = false;
    .....
}

function processLocation(){
    ....
     var coded = true;
     ....
}
```

These are not the same `coded`. To access it globally. You could do somethink like

```
var coded = false; //initialize with a proper default value function geocode() {
function geocode() {
    .... 
    coded = false;
    .....
 }

function processLocation(){
    ....
    coded = true;
    ....
}
```

Note that I'm putting `coded` outside of all the functions and access it *without* the var. You should [read](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Functions_and_function_scope) up [on this topic](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Scope_Cheatsheet) .

Comment: Also, I updated based on your comments but still the same error: http://jsfiddle.net/crFYE/12/